# Bootstrap table header and table body not aligning properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap table. I am using javascript to add rows dynamically. But the problem is that table header and table body is not aligning properly.
I have created a snippet below.

```js
function display(){ 
 
 
 var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);  
 
 //    var m = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');

   var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<input type='text'  form ='form1'  class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'typeofdr' name= 'typeofdr'  required>";
   newCell.style.width ='100px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' '  type='text' id = 'drugname' name= 'drugname'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='100px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'strdrug' name= 'strdrug'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='100px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'dosage' name= 'dosage'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dm' value= 'on' name= 'dm'  ><input type='hidden' name='dm' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'da' name= 'da' value='on'  ><input type='hidden' name='da' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'de' name= 'de' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='de' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dn' name= 'dn' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='dn' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><select  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'baf' name= 'baf'  required><option>Before</option><option>After</option></select> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='90px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'totn' name= 'totn'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='70px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'nofdays' name= 'nofdays'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';
   
  
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td class='tds'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';
   

 
}

function deleteRow(r) {
 
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(i);
   
    
}
```

```css
table.alpha th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: white;
}

table.alpha .tbalpha{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }
table.alpha .thalpha,.tbalpha{
  
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <div class="container">
       
      
      
           
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed alpha" style="width: 760px; " id="myTable1">
    <thead class="thalpha">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:100px;">Type of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:100px;">Name of Drug(Generic Name)</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:100px;">Strength of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:50px;">Dosage</th>
        <th colspan = "4" style="width:150px;" >Frequency</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:90px;">Before /After Food</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:70px;">Total No. of Tablets to be dispensed</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:50px;">No. of Days</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:30px;">Delete Row</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">M</th>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">A</th>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">E</th>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">N</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   
    <tbody  class="tbalpha">

   
    </tbody>

     <tr id="hide">
      <td><i class='fa fa-plus' style='font-size:20px; color : #ff9900;'  onclick="display()"></i></td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
   
       
       
       
       </div>
```

But when i remove display block in css, height of tbody gets reduced. Since i want the table body to scroll automatically as the height increases beyond the default height set, i have used display block.

I am not able to figure out where i am going wrong. 
Please Help Me!
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean header and table is not aligning properly? Can you explain it more? I'm bit confuse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  As i click on plus icon as shown in the above snippet,rows get added but corresponding table header columns and tbody columns  move left or right.

Comment: Okay i see. Do you want the table header to be same width of table body?

Comment: Yes sir!. But table header and table body are of same width, but still both table header and table body not getting aligned properly!. Is there anything wrong with the css?

Comment: See my posted answer and accept it as a correct answer if this is what you want

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So, here you go.

1. `min-height` and `height` apply to `block` level elements and a `table` isn't a `block` level element. So if you remove the below code your initial issue of alignment will be solved but tbody wont take the height which you have defined 200px as it is not a block level element anymore after you remove the below class.

   ```
   table.alpha .thalpha,.tbalpha{

   display:block;}
   ```
2. So here is a solution for you .

   a. You remove the above class first which will be useful to solve your initial issue.

   b. To make the height as expected you need to make your full table as `display:block` and give a `min-height` to it. refer `#myTable1` in css file.

   c. Finally in the main table `#myTable1` you have to set position relative in according to align your `hide` class (plus sign) as we are moving it out of the `table` scope and making it a separate `div`.

   d. `#hide` div is  now ready for your styling . We set it as a `position:absolute` so that it takes it position from its first `non-static` parents and set the `top` value according to your `#myTable1` min-height. And we are done.

Working copy is here below.

```js
function display(){ 
 
 
 var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);  
 
 //    var m = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');

   var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<input type='text'  form ='form1'  class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'typeofdr' name= 'typeofdr'  required>";
   newCell.style.width ='100px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' '  type='text' id = 'drugname' name= 'drugname'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='100px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'strdrug' name= 'strdrug'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='100px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'dosage' name= 'dosage'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dm' value= 'on' name= 'dm'  ><input type='hidden' name='dm' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'da' name= 'da' value='on'  ><input type='hidden' name='da' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'de' name= 'de' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='de' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dn' name= 'dn' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='dn' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='37.5px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><select  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'baf' name= 'baf'  required><option>Before</option><option>After</option></select> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='90px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'totn' name= 'totn'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='70px';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'nofdays' name= 'nofdays'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';
   
  
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td class='tds'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";
   newCell.style.width ='50px';
   

 
}

function deleteRow(r) {
 
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(i);
   
    
}
```

```css
table.alpha th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: white;
}

table.alpha .tbalpha{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }
table.alpha .thalpha,.tbalpha{
  
    /*remved*/
  }
  #myTable1 {
  display:block;
  height:500px;
  width:820px;
  position:relative;
  }
  #hide {
  width: 750px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
   position:absolute;
   top:500px;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <div class="container">
       
      
      
           
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed alpha" id="myTable1">
    <thead class="thalpha">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:100px;">Type of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:100px;">Name of Drug(Generic Name)</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:100px;">Strength of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:50px;">Dosage</th>
        <th colspan = "4" style="width:150px;" >Frequency</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:90px;">Before /After Food</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:70px;">Total No. of Tablets to be dispensed</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:50px;">No. of Days</th>
        <th rowspan = "2" style="width:30px;">Delete Row</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">M</th>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">A</th>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">E</th>
      <th style="width:37.5px;">N</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   
    <tbody  class="tbalpha">

   
    </tbody>

  
    
    </table>
   
          <div id="hide">
      <td><i class='fa fa-plus' style='font-size:20px; color : #ff9900;'  onclick="display()"></i></td>
    </div>
       
       
       </div>
```

I hope this will help you. Good luck !

Comment: From #myTable1 css. Remove min-  in height and width to fix scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css `overflow` from `auto` to overlay.

**Change your code from this:**

```
table.alpha .tbalpha{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

**With this:**

```
table.alpha .tbalpha{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:overlay;
}
```

Comment: Still the issue exists as you click on plus icon the width of tbody td cell is more than the th cell of header.

Comment: But it is not moving right when the scrollbar show? this is how you want to achieve? Am I right?

Comment: No Sir, say first column is type of drug, when you click on plus a row gets added up but,width of first td cell in tbody is more than th cell of theader .

Comment: Try to put a div inside of your <td> and <th> and put all the contents to div. Try also to remove all padding for td and th. and start to see what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

remove display:block from your table, thead, tbody tags.
they have default display styles to align your table

table.alpha .thalpha,.tbalpha{

```
display:block;
```

}
this should fix it, also you dont need to set width to td elements,
td elements, share width with th(in same column) elements

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but when i remove display block table body gets reduced,even though its height is fixed to 200px;

Comment: put table in other div and set it height or min-height, table height wont work. but you shouldnt set display block to table. that removes aligning

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `rowspan`s and `colspan`s attributes will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33147047)