# Manually Initiate Sort in Bootstrap 4 Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, bootstrap-4, datatables

I am having a problem with my bootstrap 4 datatable.  The body columns are not aligning with the header until a sort is initiated. **I also looked up some answers regarding this issue** and most of them required that "display: block" be removed - which I did - and it did not solve my issue.

All I want to do is trigger the exact same kind of sort that occurs when I click on one of the headers, but I want to do this entirely in JavaScript.

I do not want to create a function that adjusts the rows as this did not affect the header when I implemented it.

---

EDIT: A similar problem with a minimal reproducible example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152482/bootstrap-table-header-and-table-body-not-aligning-properly): However, the solutions presented in this question do not solve my issue.

Comment: Can you show us enough code so we can recreate the problem you are having? A [mre]?

Comment: The problem can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152482/bootstrap-table-header-and-table-body-not-aligning-properly

However, the solutions presented in this question do not solve my issue.

Comment: That linked example does not use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) (which is one of the tags you use in the question). So, for example, there are no clickable headers for sorting - and your question specifically mentions that. I think we might need your specific MRE, here to help recreate the problem you are facing.

Comment: I am just looking to call the sort function from JavaScript.

Comment: You can use the DataTables API: `table.order( [ 1, 'asc' ] ).draw();` - but maybe you only need the [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) - not the `order()`. I have no idea if this will work, without a MRE.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [jQuery Datatables - how to programatically sort by a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459241/jquery-datatables-how-to-programatically-sort-by-a-column)

Comment: Yes, that answered my question. Thank you.